# SUMIF/SUMIFS function criteria not working for a cell reference and returns 0 but works perfectly with specific strings

Tags: excel

looking for your help as I've searched high and low with different forums and have never gotten the answer.

I'm currently using SUMIF/SUMIFS to get the sum of payments of the same multiple names. When I would type in the specific name of the person, it works perfectly.

[image]

As you can see I have many entries so manually typing them isn't ideal. But when I type in the cell reference, it returns zero. It continuously baffles me. I tried using "=D6005" or "="&D6005 to get the contents of the cell. I've ensured that the names are already formatted as text and I still get 0s.

[image]

I'm thinking that since the string works, the sum range and criteria range works fine. So it's calling the criteria is the problem. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Perhaps there's a weird invisible character on cell D6005? Try completely clearing that cell and typing "Amamsec, Roberto" yourself.

Comment: Check the len of the cell D6005. If it's different than 16, there are some insivible chars, so you should combine your criteria with TRIM and BLANKS functions...